# How to sync firebase data on modal dismiss without reloading the page in ionic?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using a modal for getting form values which will be saved in firebase. I'm retrieving the saved data from firebase and showing it in a page. But my value is not getting updated when I dismiss the modal on form submit. Looks like I have to reload my constructor every time I dismiss the modal. Is there a better way to update the data without reloading the constructor on modal onWillDismiss?

**My home page component,**

```
    export class HomePage {
      items: any = []
      roomData:any;
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public modal:ModalController,public navParams:NavParams,public auth:AuthProvider,public af:AngularFireModule) {
        this.roomData=auth.getRoomData();
        console.log('Rooms data from firebase',this.roomData)
        this.items.push(this.roomData)
        console.log(this.items);
      }
      addItem(){
        var modal = this.modal.create(AddRoomModalPage);
        modal.present();
        // modal.onWillDismiss(function(success,err){
        //   if(err){
        //     return console.log('thsk');      
        //   }else{

        //   }
        // })
      }

    }
```

**My modal component,**

```
export class AddRoomModalPage {
   public roomDetails:FormGroup;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public auth:AuthProvider,public navParams: NavParams,public formBuilder: FormBuilder,public viewCtrl:ViewController) {
    this.roomDetails = formBuilder.group({
    roomName: ['', Validators.required],
    idealFor:['',Validators.required],
    roomMates: ['', Validators.required],
    location: ['', Validators.required],
      reqID:[false,Validators.required]
}); 
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad AddRoomModalPage');
  }

  addRoom(){
    if(this.roomDetails.valid){
      console.log(this.roomDetails.value);
      this.auth.addNewRoom(this.roomDetails.value);
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }else{
      console.log("form invalid")
    }

  }

  closeModal(){
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onDismiss() method of ModalController. Simple eg:

```
let modal = Modal.create(myModal, { data: [...] });

// Getting data from the modal:
modal.onDismiss(data => {
    // Update your props here
    console.log('MODAL DATA', data);
});

this.nav.present(modal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `ionViewWillLeave()` in your modal or use `ionViewWillEnter()` in your `HomePage` to get this event.

See the official documentation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).